# Pushing views on the first run in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have `UINavigationController` implemented in my app and what I'm trying to achieve is to determine programatically if the app has ever been launched. I need this to determine which view should I show to the user. If this is the first run I need to show different view then any other time.

It's easy when I'm not using `UINavigationController` but in this case when I use my method I'm getting rid of the `UINavigationController` hierarchy.

**This is the method I'm using to determine first run:**

```
+ (void)executeBlockAtTheFirstRun:(void (^)())firstRunBlock atAnotherRun:(void (^)())anotherRunBlock
{
    // Checking whether HasAlreadyBeenLaunched key is set to be YES
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasAlreadyBeenLaunched"]) {
        // Running block given by the user when this isn't the first run of the app
        anotherRunBlock();

        // Uncomment this if you want the log
        //NSLog(@"Application has already been launched");
    } else {
        // Seeting the bool value for key HasAlreadyBeenLaunched and synchronising user defaults
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasAlreadyBeenLaunched"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        // Running the block with code provided by the user for the first run of the app
        firstRunBlock();

        // Uncommeent this f you want the log
        // NSLog(@"This is the first run");
    }
}
```

So when I put in completion block something like:

```
NSString *storyboardID = [self hasEverBeenLaunched]? @"MainView" : @"LoginView";

self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardID];
```

And put everything in **AppDelegate.m** I'm able to manage views but as I said, my `UINavigationController` hierarchy is gone. What should I do to make everything work like it should?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a navigation controller, make a navigation controller! Instead of

```
self.window.rootViewController = 
    [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard    
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardID];
```

Say

```
UIViewController* root =         
    [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard    
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardID];
UINavigationController* nav = 
    [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: root];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

Comment: thanks this is partially what I was looking for but with this solution all hierarchy is lost anyway... I was hoping to find something like calling `rootViewController` and in it determining the first run and if necessary pushing to another view just go have this back button to root.

Answer (score 2):

Set your root view controller as `UINavigationController` visually in `storyboard`.

**Try below approach:**

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasAlreadyBeenLaunched"]) {

MainViewController *mainViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainViewController"];

    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:mainViewController] animated:YES];

    } else {

LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginViewController"];

    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:loginViewController] animated:YES];

    }
```

or you can directly keep on set your root viewController like @matt answers describes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a navigation controller first and set as a root view controller:

```
NSString *storyboardID = [self hasEverBeenLaunched]? @"MainView" : @"LoginView";
UIViewController *vc = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardID];

UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
self.window.rootViewController = nc;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create in storyboard from MainViewController segue with name "ShowLoginView" that pushes LoginViewController. And the code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    if (!self.hasEverBeenLaunched) dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
       [[(UINavigationController*)self.window.rootViewController visibleViewController] performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowLoginView" sender:nil];
    });
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: this is actually great! But I got "Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController"... Strange because everything is embeded in `UINavigationController`

Comment: make it a modal segue instead of a push

Comment: @Cojoj, I edited answer for case where rootViewController `UINavigatonController`